# Javascript & jquery manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck at what I think is a really simple thing, basically I have the following code for a slider.

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
  animate: true,
  range: "min",
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 255,
  step: 1,
  //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#slider-result" ).html( ui.value );
  },
  //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
  change: function(event, ui) { 
    $('#112').attr('value', ui.value);
  }
});
```

All works fine and dandy, the thing I want to be able to do is make the value 0 again, resetting the slider. I have a little bit setup that does it in the physical form element, but I want the visual slider to show nothing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specifically set the value of the slider

```
// This would reset the slider

$( ".slider" ).slider( "value", 0);
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is jQuery UI slider, then look at this:

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value

```
// Get or set the value option, after initialization:

// getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```